# Data only fetchs when hot reload flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this has been asked previously, but I can´t get it by my own.
I have a fetching method:

```
dynamic getResponse() async {
  response = await api.getGlobalResponse();
  resp = GlobalResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response));
  if (resp != null) {
    if (resp!.almacenes != null) {
      for (Almacen alm in resp!.almacenes!) {
        int count = 0;
        for (var opt in options) {
          if (opt != alm.name) {
            continue;
          } else {
            count += 1;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (count <= 0) options.add(alm.name.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  return response;
}
```

which resolves OK after hot reloading.

I call it on the initState() in my first screen after login, like this:

```
class _LoggedInState extends State<LoggedIn> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getResponse();
    setState(() {
      resp = resp;
    });
    page = getPage();
  }

  @override
  didChangeDependencies() {
    getResponse();
    setState(() {
      resp = resp;
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (getToken()) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: page,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return getLoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

The getPage() returns correctly loaded from fetch after hot reload, but I cant figure out how to auto load from the very first time.
I have already tryed ValueNotifiers and ValueListenables, without luck.
willyou please help this fool?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally recommended to avoid using the `dynamic` type in Dart, as it can lead to potential runtime errors if the wrong type of data is returned or passed in. Instead, it is better to specify the specific type that you are expecting.

If you are sure that you have to use `dynamic` here, then change return type of `getResponse` to `Future<dynamic>` because the function is asynchronous.

In the widget, in `initState` and `didChangeDependencies` methods after calling `getResponse` wait for its response then call `setState`.

```dart
getResponse().then((resp) =>
  setState(() {
    resp = resp;
  }));
```

---

This code calls the `getResponse` method and waits for the response to be returned. Once it is received, it calls the `setState` method and updates the state of the widget with the returned data.